# Script not getting executed as per expectation

Tags: scripting, path, tcsh

I have two Perl scripts at a predefined location in Unix. This predefined location is set in path variable (`$PATH`). Now when i try to run first script (from any location) the script runs successfully while for second script (at same path as that of previous script) throws an error saying

```
ScriptB: Command not found
```

My shell is tcsh and permissions given to both scripts are the same.

What can be the probable reason for such erroneous behaviour?

Comment: What does `sed l\;q /path/to/ScriptB` tell you? Is `ScriptB` executable (`ls -ld /path/to/ScriptB`)?

Comment: Is `ScriptB` executable?  Does it have a shebang at the top which points to the right place?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - Script is at path : /path/to `sed l\;q /path/to/ScriptB` returns `#!/path/to/bin/perl\r$` `#!/path/to/bin/perl`

Comment: @Flup - Answer to both questions YES...

Comment: @StephaneChazelas @cjm - Can you please explain what `sed l\;q /path/to/ScriptB` is trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ScriptB has CRLF line endings.  Since the kernel doesn't support CRLF, it's trying to execute a program named `"/path/to/bin/perl\r"` (where `\r` indicates a CR).  That program doesn't exist.  Convert ScriptB to LF line endings.  (Thank [Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/stephane-chazelas) for [asking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76212/script-not-getting-executed-as-per-expectation#comment111301_76212) the right question.  The `\r` in the `sed` output indicates the problem.)

`sed l\;q FILE` runs 2 sed commands (separated by a semicolon, which needs to be escaped because it's also a shell metacharacter).  From `man sed`:

```
l  List out the current line in a "visually unambiguous" form
q  Immediately quit the sed script without processing any more input,
   except that if auto-print is not disabled the current pattern space will be printed.
```

So `l` prints the first line in a format that makes normally hidden characters like CR visible, and then `q` quits after the first line.

Comment: But how two lines are returned by sed command in discussion. As per your explanation it should just return one line i.e. the first line of first

Comment: Also if the problem is with script why the error thrown is `Command not found` instead error should be thrown by perl

Comment: I abbreviated the explanation of `q` because it's only the first line of output that's significant.

Comment: The problem is that the kernel doesn't start `perl` because you told it to look for `perl\r`.  Perl can handle scripts with CRLF line endings; it's the kernel that has an issue with them.